# Где на практике используются транзакции с уровнем изолированности SERIALIZABLE?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, serializable

Дорогое коммьюнити, подскажите пожалуйста, где на практике (в каких ситуациях) при работе с базой данных ORACLE могут применяться транзакции с уровнем изолированности SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: А в связи с чем возник такой вопрос? Пока вопрос слишком общий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кусочек [отсюда](https://www.sql.ru/blogs/oracleandsql/2259)

> Для чего используется уровень изоляции на практике SERIALIZABLE?
> Обычно используется при выполнении сложных запросов, для построения
> отчетов, где необходима точность вычислений и данные в базе постоянно
> изменяются.
>
> Например, отчет по платежам строится час, один из запросов вычисляет
> итоговую сумму, другие запросы вычисляют под итоги, если таблица
> платежей изменится, поступают новые платежи, тогда цифры, итогов и под
> итогов разойдутся, не будут совпадать. В этом случае целесообразно
> использовать режим SERIALIZABLE, чтобы данные ко времени начала
> построения отчета, не отличались от данных к окончанию построения
> отчета.